# adding user to LDAP through java application causes group search

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a spring application that adds users to slapd.  the users are added and associated to a group.
the application is modularized and different modules have the ability to create a user to be added to slapd.  the original developers did not take into consideration the group and two of the modules would create a user that could not log in to the third module.  once I corrected this, I see slapd doing a search on all dn's in the group:

```
conn=1020 op=1 SRCH base="ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" scope=1 deref=3 filter="(member=uid=hack-a-tack,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com)"
```

this search then loops through every user in the group and not just the one in the filter.

```
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: conn=1020 op=1 SRCH base="ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" scope=1 deref=3 filter="(member=uid=hack-a-tack,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com)"
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: conn=1020 op=1 SRCH attr=cn
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => access_allowed: search access to "ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" "entry" requested
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => dn: [2] ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => acl_get: [3] attr entry
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => acl_mask: access to entry "ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com", attr "entry" requested
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => acl_mask: to all values by "cn=manager,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com", (=0)
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= check a_dn_pat: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= check a_dn_pat: cn=manager,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= acl_mask: [2] applying write(=wrscxd) (stop)
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= acl_mask: [2] mask: write(=wrscxd)
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => slap_access_allowed: search access granted by write(=wrscxd)
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => access_allowed: search access granted by write(=wrscxd)
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => bdb_filter_candidates
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: #011EQUALITY
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: bdb_idl_fetch_key: [01872a84]
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= bdb_filter_candidates: id=0 first=0 last=0
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: bdb_idl_fetch_key: %ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => bdb_filter_candidates
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: #011AND
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => bdb_list_candidates 0xa0
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => bdb_filter_candidates
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: #011EQUALITY
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: bdb_idl_fetch_key: [757973d2]
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= bdb_filter_candidates: id=1 first=6 last=6
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= bdb_list_candidates: id=1 first=6 last=6
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= bdb_filter_candidates: id=1 first=6 last=6
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => test_filter
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]:     EQUALITY
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => access_allowed: search access to "cn=USER,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com" "member" requested
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => dn: [2] ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => acl_get: [3] attr member
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => acl_mask: access to entry "cn=USER,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com", attr "member" requested
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => acl_mask: to value by "cn=manager,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com", (=0)
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= check a_dn_pat: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= check a_dn_pat: cn=manager,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= acl_mask: [2] applying write(=wrscxd) (stop)
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: <= acl_mask: [2] mask: write(=wrscxd)
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => slap_access_allowed: search access granted by write(=wrscxd)
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: => access_allowed: search access granted by write(=wrscxd)
Jun 12 10:07:16 cm-coret1 slapd[8145]: dnMatch -3#012#011"uid=redients,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"#012#011"uid=hack-a-tack,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"
........> just continues to loop after this
```

this then blocks all the other connections attempting to do any kind of search or update.
Does anyone know if I can configure the SLAPD.conf to ship this search?

Answer (score 0):

'Ship this search'? Do you mean *stop* this search? The answer to that is no, you will have to fix the application that is doing it.